# Do the @ and ` symbols have any use in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, syntax, operators, naming-conventions

I've become quite familiar with JavaScript variable naming conventions and operators and have noticed that pretty much every ASCII character on my keyboard has some sort of use as part of a variable name or operator...

Save for the (`) character and the (@) character... I've even checked my sources and Googled my butt off to find out more... but to no avail...

So tell me, my fellow tech-heads... **IS** there any use of the (`) or the (@) symbols in JavaScript?

Comment: @p.s.w.g This is by no means a helpful answer, dude... I'm fully aware of the practicalities of these symbols as part of a string... What I am asking is the possibility of using them in some other convention such as an operator or as part of a variable name or something other than as part of a string within the JavaScript paradigm.

Comment: @Eliseod'Annunzio—I don't see any answers, only helpful comments…

Comment: @RobG I couldn't help but smirk at this comment... I'm gonna +1 you for that...

Comment: @guest I just read about it there, it's supposedly been marked as obsolete... So it's no longer being used... what a shame...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@` is used in E4X. E4X is not widely available though.

```
var node = <item desc="first" />;
var nodeDesc = node.@desc;
```

` is used in template strings in ES6.

```
var i = 9;
var message = `I could eat like ${ i } of those.`;
```